# Trying to replace a html attribute using a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to take an `a` element and take the information from the `data-id` attribute and store it into a variable. I want to then splice this variable so I get the part that I need and implement it into another variable with some text. From that I then want to replace the `src` attribute of an `iframe` with the variable. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working at all and I can't find the issue.

Here is the code:

```
$('.watchvideo').click(function(){
    var idu = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var id = "//www.youtube.com/embed/"idu.substr(27,37);

    $('.videofeatem').setAttribute("src", id);

});
```

Comment: if you add a jsfiddle it would be easier to debug, but from the code it looks like you need 
    var id = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+idu.substr(27,37);

Comment: `var id = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + idu.substr(27,37);` Check if this works. Seems like you missed a `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML, it's tough to be sure, but a `+` fixes the obvious problem:

```
$('.watchvideo').click(function(){
    var idu = $(this).data('id');
    var id = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + idu.substr(27,37);

    $('.videofeatem').attr("src", id);
 });
```

Also, note that `data-xxx` attributes can be read by jQuery as `.data('xxx')`

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 issues in code:

1) concatenating substring

2) setting attribute via jquery

```
var id = "//www.youtube.com/embed/"+idu.substr(27,37);
$('.videofeatem').attr("src", id);
```

Comment: This answer maybe covers all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Simply.

```
var id = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + idu.substr(27,37);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, use the .attr() method instead of the .setAttribute().